# Connect rails app in Docker container to external Postgresql Database via URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, docker

I have a docker container with web rails app. Also I have external database on my osx machine. If I exec on osx:

```
psql "postgres://postgres:testing@0.0.0.0:5432/movies_development"
```

I run okay

If I run it in container I'll receive

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Have any ideas how to connect to external database from container?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way for connect app in docker container to local database which located on my osx.

0.0.0.0:5432 is an localhost address of container (not a localhost of osx) and we must set new one:

1. Find osx Ip local address in Preferences > Network Settings (my was 192.168.0.102)
2. Add this Ip to line `listener_address: '192.168.0.102, localhost'` of postgresql config file.
3. Add extra line with Ip 192.168.0.102, host and md5 to pg_hba.conf file
4. Restart Postgresql

Set connection settings in app via ENV like: postgres://postgres:testing@192.168.0.102:5432/movies_development

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reasons as per your question :

- Have you exposed `EXPOSE 5432` during your docker image build ? or before starting container with `docker run -it -d --name $container_name -p 5432:5432 $image_name` ? If NO than you must have to do any of above changes than and than it can connect to externally hosted database.
- If your are going inside your docker container with `docker exec -it $container_name bash` and executing command this `psql "postgres://postgres:testing@0.0.0.0:5432/movies_development"` then there must be psql client installed in your docker container with proper `$PATH` variable otherwise it will throw error like command not found/no such file or directory.
- **Note:** if your application is using some other way to communicate with database than your application will work without psql client program.

Hope this help.Thank you!